# What determines Technological Enlightenment rate?

Tags: stellaris

I am trying to enlighten some primitive empire I have an observation post on:

[image: Enlightennment Rate]

The rate is `+0 Per Month` (while it is probably `0.x` per month since it still progresses).

What determines this rate? And is there a way to speed it up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Stellaris Wiki page on Pre-FTL Species](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Pre-FTL_species#Primitive_species) fully explains this.

> **Technological Enlightenment:** This mission consists of bringing the primitives up to the level of technology a spacefaring empire enjoys. This can be a monumental effort and will require a significant investment of time and a monthly cost of 5 energy and 5 Society research. *The speed at which technological enlightenment proceeds depends on which level of technology the primitive civilization has - Machine Age primitives take 50 months to enlighten, while Steam Age primitives take 100 months to enlighten.* Once the primitives have achieved space flight, they will be turned into a Protectorate of their benefactors.

Here's a table copied over, showing the percentage per month depending on the type of civilization, and the total number of months needed:

```
 - Bronze Age          0.2%     500 Months  

 - Iron Age            0.3%     334 Months  

 - Late Medieval Age   0.4%     250 Months  

 - Renaissance Age     0.5%     200 Months  

 - Steam Age           1.0%     100 Months  

 - Industrial Age      1.5%      67 Months  

 - Machine Age         2.0%      50 Months  

 - Atomic Age          2.5%      40 Months  

 - Early Space Age     2.5%      40 Months
```

Your progress can be sped up or slowed down by random events. The ones I have had seemed like they were likely based on the relationship between our ethical traits. For instance, if we're both materialistic, they might be able to learn what I'm teaching faster than expected.

Answer (score 4):

(not wanting to just delete part of the above post, so adding another answer)

I found this post while staring at a 0/Month progress Rate myself, when I suddenly got an event about the natives being more amiable and understanding of the teachings than expected, adding another 20% of progress.

So, DCShannon up here, while extremely helpful, is partially wrong: There are speed up events, they just seem to be a lot rarer than setback events.
Citation: Personal Experience which I failed to record. D'oh.

Comment: A good citation would be the event entry in ```observation_events.txt``` called ```# Quick Learning Primitives```. :)

Comment: I've run into a speed up event now as well, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Unlike CyberEagle above, I've actually *only* had positive events while helping 5-10 Primitive Feudalism societies.